MongoDb $filter with $or not working as expected
Please open this playground and follow with me: playground
I have a collection names Pages where each document has keys Urls and DraftUrls which is an array of objects as below:
IncomingUrl: string;
EclipseId: string;
Status: string;
RedirectionLink: string;
Validity: Date;
Config: ConfigData[];
Indexing: boolean;

Now, I just want to find the count of URLs which have either a status of Inactive or have an expired Validity. Also I want a few more info like GroupName and TemplateName.
I tried to use $filter with $or as you can see in the playground but the issue is that its giving me the count of all URLs without checking for the specified conditions in cond.
At first I thought there was an issue with how the Validity is checked but then I removed that part and checked just for the Inactive state, but still it gave me count of all Urls

https://mongoplayground.net/p/DzpdhiJfY7W do the comparisons like this. https://mongoplayground.net/p/kt5R1aLaRfm

Some issues in the linked playground from your question: 1. You reference a field in DraftUrls/Urls called Validity but that field doesn't exist anywhere. So the date check will always be false. 2. Your $or clause has 'Status': 'Validity' - shouldn't that be Active/Inactive/Valid ? 3. Since you check for "Status": "Inactive" first, you don't need to check for "Status": "Active" (or "Status": "Validity") in the second part of the $or. Unless there are other Statuses also.

Your cond expression in the $filter is incorrect. Modify so that the $filter operator should be as below:
{
    $addFields: {
      filteredUrls: {
        $filter: {
          input: isDraftB ? '$DraftUrls' : '$Urls',
          cond: {
            $or: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.Status",
                  "Inactive"
                ]
              },
              {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.Status",
                      "Validity"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $gte: [
                      "$$this.Validity",
                      currentDate
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

